# JavaFX binding and property change

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I'm working in JavaFX with bindings and properties.
I have a `Label label` and a `Person currentPerson`.
I have the following code:

```
label.textProperty().bind(currentPerson.nameProperty());
```

Then I have in another section of code:

```
currentPerson = newPerson;   //newPerson is a given Person instance
```

This way the `textProperty` of `label` doesn't update!

But if I do in that section of code:

```
currentPerson.setName(newPerson.getName());
```

then this updates the `textProperty` of `label`.

My question is: why does the second way update the `textProperty` of `label`, while the first doesn't, even though the `nameProperty` of `currentPerson` is changed in both cases?

Comment: `label.textProperty().bind(currentPerson.nameProperty());` is only evaluated once. At that time the expression `currentPerson.nameProperty()` is evaluated and modifying the `currentPerson` variable does not result in the above code line being executed again. `currentPerson.setName(newPerson.getName());` modifies `currentPerson`'s `name` property and therefore has an effect to the `text` property that is bound to it. You probably should do `label.textProperty().bind(newPerson.nameProperty())` instead. You could move this code to a new method if this helps you avoid code duplication.

Comment: @fabian Ok, but if I print the  `nameProperty` of `currentPerson`, after the assignment and also outside the body of the assignment, it is changed to the `nameProperty` contained in `newPerson`. I understand what you say, but the `nameProperty` has changed and the evaluation is not executed again (why?). Anyway, thank you for the quick reply, maybe I will follow your suggestion of binding to `newPerson` instead of `currentPerson`.

Comment: @Kenna *"If I print the `nameProperty` of `currentPerson` after the assignment... it has changed."* I doubt it; I suspect you are getting the `nameProperty` from the *new* value of `currentPerson`. If you do `StringProperty name = currentPerson.nameProperty();` and print `name`; then do `currentPerson = newPerson ;` and print `name` again, it will not have changed.

Comment: @James_D Yes, you're totally right! So this is the reason! I understand now, maybe...after the assignment, `currentPerson` was referring to `newPerson`, and the print of `currentPerson.nameProperty` was actually a print of `newPerson.nameProperty`. But when I come to print the real `nameProperty` of `currentPerson` (by making the assignment you suggested to me) then I print the old `nameProperty`, also after the assignment! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997224/2114786), You've lost your first binding after :

```
currentPerson = newPerson;
```

The solution is either (re)bind `currentPerson` after any assignment to `currentPerson`, or instead, use a method to pass the `newPerson` data, like:

```
currentPerson.setPerson(newPerson);


public class Person{

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    // ....


    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        // ....
        this.name.set(person.name.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, after the assignment `currentPerson` refers to another object, not the one that was bound. And it's exactly what I'm doing right now, a method that updates to the properties of the argument! :) Thank tou

Answer (score 1):

I think the most basic answer to your question is that, after the line `currentPerson = newPerson;`, the `currentPerson` object is not the same object that was bound to `label` previously.

Comment: Well, yes I think that's the point. See comments above, they basically say the same thing. So the basic reason is that Java pass by-value, not by-reference.

Comment: Yes! Java passes (**a reference to an object**) by value.

Answer (score -1):

It must be occurring that you have set the `bind` in relation to that `person's name`, so when you use `getName`, it updates the `label`