# Handling nested Properties in JavaFX / TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I want to have a window which shows info about certain `ViewModel`

Suppose you have a simple Person:

```
class Person(name: String) {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
}
```

and have instance of `Person` save in property:

```
val personProperty = SimpleObjectProperty(Person("John"))
```

what's the correct solution to show Person's name in label?

Using this:

```
label(personProperty.value.nameProperty)
```

Will not update when I update the property's person:

```
personProperty.value = Person("Joe")
```

(That's obvious because only the reference changes, not the value itself)

So is there any good way to do this or do I have to manually add listeners for `personProperty` and update which `Person` does label point to?

EDIT:
I also found this question: [JavaFX binding and property change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996558/javafx-binding-and-property-change), but it doesn't contain anything new and useful that I didn't know about, is there any TornadoFX-specific way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the `ItemViewModel` does for you. If you want to make a binding for the name property that updates automatically, outside of an `ItemViewModel`, you can use the TornadoFX feature `select`:

```
val nameProperty = personProperty.select { it.nameProperty }
```

Answer (score 0):

A listener can be attached to the property:

```
personProperty.onChange {
    it?.nameProperty.let(nameLabel.textProperty().bind)
}
```

This can be wrapped in extension function to simplify the task.